# Does python support iterating through *args argument?

Tags: python

```
def my_tup(*args):
    for _ in args:
        return _


print(my_tup(1,2,3,8,6))
```

I'm getting 1 as my output

Just as a list, I want to know if I can iterate the `*args`.

My expected output was `(1,2,3,8,6)`.

Comment: You can iterate, but you're returning on the first iteration.

Comment: `*args` is the parameter, not the argument. The arguments to this call are `1`, `2`, `3`, `8`, and `6`. The purpose of the starred parameter is to *collect* all positional arguments not otherwise assigned to parameters in a single tuple bound to the name of the parameter.

Comment: `args` is a tuple, and is iterable like any other tuple.

Comment: Consider what `*` is doing: It allows a variable number of arguments to a function. Without it, that is a fixed function argument. The mechanism is all the arguments are gathered into a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

The `return` statement in the body of the loop terminates the successful iteration early.

```
def my_tup(*args):
    for _ in args:
        print(_)

my_tup(1,2,3,8,6)
```

produces

```
1
2
3
8
6
```

as output.

It's not clear what `my_tup` is supposed to do; you *could* simply write

```
def my_tup(*args):
    return args
```

because `args` is already a value of type `tuple`.

Answer (score 0):

It does support iterating through *args argument. See for yourself. Defining

```
def f(*args):
    for arg in args:
        print(arg)
```

which implies iteration, is assuming, e.g. the following usage

```
>>> f('a', 'b')
a
b
```